# Why is there brown stuff in my dog's ear?

Tags: dogs, health, diseases, injury

I don't know when this happened.
Just a moment ago my dog started to scratch his ears kind a rough,I though it was weird so I check his ears and I see this.

What happened here ? I'm really worried about my dog.

[image]

[image]

Comment: it might be mites,take your dog to the vet for treatment,

Answer (score 5):

This is excessive ear wax, probably due to an ear infection.

You can try cleaning the wax with a moist cotton swab. There are special dog ear cleaning solutions that can dissolve the wax and some have additional beneficial properties. Most dogs are more accepting of ear cleaning when you mimic a licking motion. **Never use Q-tips / cotton buds in a dog's ear** because the risk of injury is too high.

If the ear wax returns within a day or two, your dog shakes his head a lot or rubs and scratches his ears, you should visit a vet. Ear infections can be caused either by ear mites, bacteria or fungi and the vet needs to determine the cause to give you the correct treatment. As treatment you usually get ear drops that numb the itching and fight the germs. If an infection is not treated, it can become chronic, sometimes lasting several months and in extreme cases the dogs have to get surgery to remove the focus of the disease.

Comment: Do not use Q-tips, just lick his ears :D
It took me a moment to get what you meant.

Comment: In my experience with my dog, she will dig in her ear with her back paws when they start bothering her, and they typically will look like this to a degree.  If left uncleaned, an infection could brew up (or worsen if already present).  Our vet gave us special drops that we can use to treat ear infections, as well as a bottle of ear cleaning fluid that we are suppose to use about every two weeks to clean her ears.  I've also heard it's possible that yeast infections can occur within the ears, although I believe that is more yellowish in color.